# Update attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, magento2.2.6

When I select more then one product and try to update attribute

it goes to catalog/product_action_attribute/edit/ and get

Has any idea about this error?

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class adminhtml/catalog_product_helper_form_msrp_enabled does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class adminhtml/catalog_product_helper_form_msrp_enabled does not exist
#0 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('adminhtml/catal...')
#1 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('adminhtml/catal...')
#2 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('adminhtml/catal...')
#3 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('adminhtml/catal...', Array)
#4 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Factory.php(81): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('adminhtml/catal...', Array)
#5 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/AbstractForm.php(155): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory->create('adminhtml/catal...', Array)
#6 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Fieldset.php(212): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\AbstractForm->addField('msrp_enabled', 'adminhtml/catal...', Array, false)
#7 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form.php(196): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset->addField('msrp_enabled', 'select_msrp_ena...', Array)
#8 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tab/Attributes.php(95): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset), Array)
#9 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab\Attributes->_prepareForm()
#10 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(666): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->_beforeToHtml()
#11 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(465): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#12 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/tabs.phtml(57): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab\Attributes))
#13 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/srv/public_htm...')
#14 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tabs), '/srv/public_htm...', Array)
#15 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/srv/public_htm...')
#16 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(126): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#17 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#18 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#19 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('attributes_tabs')
#20 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('attributes_tabs')
#21 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('attributes_tabs')
#22 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('attributes_tabs', false)
#23 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('attributes_tabs', false)
#24 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('left', false)
#25 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('left')
#26 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('left')
#27 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('left', false)
#28 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('left', false)
#29 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('side.col', false)
#30 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('side.col')
#31 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('side.col')
#32 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('side.col', false)
#33 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('side.col', false)
#34 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.conta...', false)
#35 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#36 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#37 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.conta...', false)
#38 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.main.conta...', false)
#39 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content', false)
#40 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#41 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#42 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', false)
#43 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.content', false)
#44 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#45 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#46 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#47 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#48 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#49 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page', false)
#50 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#51 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#52 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', false)
#53 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('backend.page', false)
#54 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#55 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#56 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#57 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#58 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#59 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(492): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#60 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
```

Comment: What's the Magento Version ?

Comment: I used Magento ver. 2.2.6

Comment: please open app/etc/config.php find Magento_Msrp=>1 module enable or not.

Comment: 'Magento_Msrp' => 1, is enable.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: nope, I am still searching